# Connection between invertible matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

In many questions I read lately about eigenvalues I am asked to proove theorms about the connection between invertible matrices and their eigenvalues.
Given an invertible matrix $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{F})$, is there a general connection between $A$'s eigenvalues and it's invertablity?
For example: $A$ is invertible iff $0$ is not $A$'s eigenvalue.

Comment: You might check your last sentence;  if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Av = 0v = 0$ for some vector $v \ne 0$; thus $\ker(A) \ne 0$, and $A$ can't be invertible.  What do you think?  Cheers!

Comment: Of course.. thank you.

Comment: My pleasure!  Thanx for the edit!  ***endorsed!!!***

Comment: By the way, I think bburGsamoh T's answer is the long and short of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is invertible if and only if it does not have zero as an eigenvalue.

Comment: is that the only thing to say about the connection?

Comment: Yuppers, that does it!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: It's the only connection I can come up with; in general invertibility of a matrix can be reduced to showing it has a trivial kernel. That by definition says $Ax=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: Many more related facts might be adduced.  The matrix is invertible if its determinant, which is the product of eigenvalues up to algebraic multiplicity, is nonzero.  But this gives no better information than above.  The eigenvalues of the matrix inverse are scalar inverses of the original matrix eigenvalues.  But this seems only related to the Question.